# What is really happening when using variables?

Tags: function, variables, scope, memory-address

I have a really basic question about something that I've never paid much attention to until now:

I noticed that when creating a function (in JS or Python) that uses a variable from the outer scope, the function is not defined using the value of the variable but rather the variable itself. So if I change the value of the variable the function will use the new value.
This is what I mean

```
let a = 10;
function printA(){
  console.log(a);
}
printA(); // => 10
a = 20;
printA(); // => 20
```

---

```
a = 10
def printA():
  print(a)
printA() # => 10
a = 20
printA() # => 20
```

I thought this was only going to work of objects because of the way you can modify an object inside a function but not primitive variables because there's no way to change their value without reasigning them. I guess this is a different story.

What I'm trying to understand is: when typing a variable name is typing its memory address what I'm really doing? Does this happen with all languages?

Comment: I can't pull a straight question to answer from this but the concept that seems to have started you down this route is usually termed `variable capture`. You may find lots of resources by searching on that (plus the languages you're interested in)

Comment: Basically my question is: when I create a function like `printA()` that uses a variable that is not an argument, is the variable bound forever to the function by its address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I create a function like printA() that uses a variable that is not an argument, is the variable bound forever to the function by its address?

The variable `a` is "captured" by the function. The specifics of *how* that happens are usually implementation details and may result in the compiler/interpreter producing code that doesn't much resemble the original.

For instance, in C# (I know, not one of the languages you mentioned, but it's the one I'm most familiar with), the compiler will create a separate hidden class which actually contains fields for the variables that are captured by a lambda or nested function. It then accesses these fields rather than plain variables.

> by its address

Variables don't typically *have* **an** address. For instance, every time you call a method, it will typically have an "activation record" of some kind created, that will typically contain its variables. But note that these records are not at some *fixed* location, which is how you can have parallel execution of methods, recursion, etc, without interference. (Some older BASICs did have fixed activation records, which is why they didn't allow for recursion). These activation records may typically be placed on some kind of *stack*.

But as I say, for captured variables, the compiler will typically need to do even more so that those variables aren't just stored in an activation record, and so that *their lifetime* is no longer tied to a single call.